# Flutter Path Provider with Hive OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1

Tags: flutter, dart, path, flutter-hive

I am using [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) and [Path Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) inside my app and on the simulator everything is working just fine. But when running my app on a real device (iPhone X, iOS 15) I get this error:

> [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9B79CFB2-7AF9-4F2E-BD65-67950D247FEF/Documentshive_db' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)

This is the code where it is throwing the error:

```
static Future<void> init() async {
    var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    // make sure it exists
    await dir.create(recursive: true);

    var dbPath = '${dir.path}hive_db';

    Hive
      ..init(dbPath)
      ..registerAdapter(HiveMedicamentAdapter())
      ..registerAdapter(HiveVitalsAdapter())
      ..registerAdapter(HiveDiscomfortAdapter())
      ..registerAdapter(HiveEmergencyContactAdapter())
      ..registerAdapter(HiveEventAdapter());

    await Hive.openBox<HiveMedicament>(HiveKeys.medicaments); // <- throws above error
    await Hive.openBox<HiveVitals>(HiveKeys.vitals);
    await Hive.openBox<List>(HiveKeys.discomforts);
    await Hive.openBox<bool>(HiveKeys.auth);
    await Hive.openBox<bool>(HiveKeys.syncLocalWithBackend);
    await Hive.openBox<HiveEmergencyContact>(HiveKeys.emergencyContacts);
    await Hive.openBox<String>(HiveKeys.pdfSecret);
    await Hive.openBox<HiveEvent>(HiveKeys.event);
  }
```

I searched for any Hive issues or path provider issues but couldn't find anything. What am I missing here? I thought Hive or Path Provider does not need any extra permissions.

Any help is appreciated! Let me know if you need more info!

Comment: Sadly no answers or hint!

Answer (score 0):

The result of calling `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` will give you the path to a directory, not the path inside to that directory, so if you print it you will notice that the returned path doesn't end with a trailing forward slash:

```
"/var/.../.../Documents"
```

and given that you are directly concatenating this to the string `"hive_db"` the last section of the newly formed path will be `"Documentshive_db"`. Which I'm guessing that in the simulator won't be a problem given that you are creating that directory in the next line (because it doesn't exists).

But as the error states, you are not permitted to create a new directory inside the documents directory of the real device and hence you get the error when trying to do so.

A solution would be to add a forward slash in the concatenation between  `"Documents"` and `"hive_db"` so the final path becomes:

```
"/var/.../.../Documents/hive_db"
```

Please, check the documentation of the path_provider plugin and do tests to see if this behaviour is the same in all platforms you are targeting, perhaps some do return the path with a trailing forward slash and so this solution won't work, in which case you can perhaps check if the path does have a trailing forward slash, and if not add it yourself.